# How add option of "more" in navigation to bar?

Tags: react-native, tabbar

I have an app that has 6 menu options, so I need a button on the tab navigation to bar that opens as a drop down so I don't have too many buttons on the tab navigation .

It's possible?

I tried to do it with Drawer, but the navigation tab disappears when I open the other pages. Can anyone help?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow.  Can you add a [mcve] to your post please?